# Upgrading to 3.5 break multisite

Tags: localization, upgrades

Just upgraded to Craft 3.5+ and now all my non-primary site's pages are not found.
All my english page (primary site is in french) returns a "Template not found".
So "en/anypage" returns a "Template not found" now.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What version of Craft did you upgrade from?

Comment: I've upgraded from 3.4.30.
Rolling back to 3.4.30 solved the problem, but I need to be able to upgrade to 3.5.x without breaking the multisite function.

Comment: Sounds like this could be a bug? I'd email craft support (support@craftcms.com).